# Configure ChannelId for Expo Push Notifications

Tags: node.js, expo

I have the following code, where I send push notifications from a node server. My app receives the notifications, but without sound or vibration.

```js
service.sendNotifications = (listTokens, textMessage) => {
     let expo = new Expo();
     let messages = [];
     for( let token of listTokens){

        if(!Expo.isExpoPushToken(token)) {
            console.error(`Token ${token} is not valid`);
            continue;
        }

        messages.push({
            to: token,
            sound: 'default',
            body: textMessage,
            android: {
                channelId: 'my-channel',
              },
            priority: 'high',
            data: {},
        })
     }

     let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
     let tickets = [];

     (async () => {
        for(let chunk of chunks) {
            try{
                let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
                tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
     })();
```

To solve it, I was told to use a channel. I've configured that in my App and when I send a test notification from https://expo.io/dashboard/notifications everything goes as expected.

How to configure channelId in the server side?

Comment: i think you don't have to use android field inside messages.push. try using only channelId